# Windows 7 x64 calling convention and single parameter passing

Tags: c++, windows, 64-bit, driver, calling-convention

I'm currently trying to track down a bug in a driver that seems to be having problems with calling the kernel function `IoFreeIrp` to release IRP memory back into the non-paged pool.

I'm set a breakpoint in the `IoFreeIrp` function and when it's hit, I can see the values contained within the registers, however I'm not sure which register actually contains the IRP that needs to be freed.

From what I know about x64 Windows 7, it uses the x64 calling convention, which means the first four parameters are passed by register, Microsoft state that:

> The arguments are passed in registers RCX, RDX, R8, and R9.

So, maybe I'm being a bit naive here, but I assumed that the IRP that needed to be freed would always be specified within the RCX register, but I'm guessing that I'm wrong.  As when the breakpoint is hit, the RCX register sometimes contains what appears to be an IRP, and sometimes not so.

Microsoft state that the IoFreeIrp function takes one parameter:

```
The IoFreeIrp routine releases a caller-allocated IRP from the caller's IoCompletion routine.
Syntax

C++

VOID IoFreeIrp(
_In_  PIRP Irp
);

Parameters

Irp [in]
Pointer to the IRP that is to be released.
```

The Microsoft document also states that integer values are passed in these registers, so I'm not sure if pointer qualifies as an integer value, I think it does, right?

If anyone could offer a bit of advice on reading the register values upon hitting the breakpoint, I'd appreciate it.

Thanks.

Comment: Chicken-and-egg question.  You'll have a problem with IoFreeIrp() if you pass a bad IRP pointer.  So don't expect to find a sane parameter value back.

Comment: Ahh OK I get you.  I was mostly wondering which register I should be lookin in for the parameter.  I'm also looking at some valid IRP driver activity, but again I'm not sure where I should be looking to see the parameter.  Thanks though.